# Setting role in SiteMapNode Sub Node

Tags: asp.net, roles, sitemapprovider

These Site Map Node is in Web.Config

```
<siteMapNode title="Hotel Setup" roles="Administrator,Hotel Admin">
  <siteMapNode url="~/Page/HotelSetup/RoomTypeManagement.aspx" title="Room Types" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/Page/HotelSetup/AddOns/AddOnCategoryProperties.aspx" title="Add On Categories" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/Page/HotelSetup/AddOn.aspx" title="Add Ons" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/Page/HotelSetup/Package.aspx" title="Packages" />     
  <siteMapNode url="~/Page/PriceTools/Promotion.aspx" title="Promotions" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/Page/PriceTools/PromotionAddOn.aspx" title="AddOns Incentive" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/Page/SupportAdmin/TranslationProperty.aspx" title="Translations" />
</siteMapNode>
```

Is there anyway to made some sub sitemapnode in hotel setup can be accessed only by administrator but not hotel admin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it need to be set in location path